# Shareable Key Value Pair in Android

Tags: android

Good day mates! I am wondering if there are ways to create a shareable key-value pair in Android? What I meant by shareable is that a file that can be viewed in file manager. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to save data to external storage you need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to your manifest. External storage means, that it can be accessed from arbitrary app.

In the following is a code snippet hat creates a file in your pictures directory. You can use any directory you want.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

```
public File getAlbumStorageDir(Context context, String albumName) {
 // Get the directory for the app's private pictures directory. 
 File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(
         Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
 if (!file.mkdirs()) {
     Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
 }
 return file;
```

}

Having created the file you can use it like you are used to it from Java.

Either create an txt-file or you use an objectoutputstream.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response mate! What I have in mind is that, is there a way to create a key-value pair like that of a SharedPreferences that can be shared using bluetooth, etc. Because later I want to save that "key-value pair file" to my server. Is that possible? :)

Comment: Create an Object that contains two Strings, a key and value. This object you can persist using objectoutputstream